# swift reload views when value changed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift5

I have some views.

A MainViewController with 6 buttons.
Here every button would start a function.

A tableview with 6 cells and each cells open an other ButtonVC. ( FirstButtonVC, Second... )
In every ButtonVC there is a picker.
There is an option in the picker ( it says -- ) which is basically nil so it will disable the button on the main VC.

My problem is that when I set it to this disabled option, or even if i enable a button with the picker, in the MainVC the button's ui won't refresh only after stopping and starting the application again in the simulator.

S my question is:
How can I refresh the MainViewController's ui from the ButtonVC so when the user returns to the MainViewController he can already see the updated ui with the updated buttons?

I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: You should do that in the viewWillAppear(animated:) func of MainViewController.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to approach this problem is by solving UI updates in the

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   // Add you code here
}
```

Of your MainViewController.